# lastb/btmp does not work and is empty

Tags: ssh, log-files

I tried to clean the lastb/btmp and last/wtmp with

```
cat /dev/null > /var/log/wtmp
cat /dev/null > /var/log/btmp
```

and then, I found the last/wtmp works as normal, but the lastb/btmp does not work, there is only `btmp begins Fri Oct 15 17:46:14 2021`. So, I tried to renew the file with

```
rm -f /var/log/btmp*
touch /var/log/btmp
chown root.utmp /var/log/btmp
chmod 600 /var/log/btmp
```

However, it does not work. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: It seems that there might be a 'bug' where the real users would not be recorded. I used the root and my personal usename, the lastb did not record anything while a non-real user could be recorded.